# Enfocar sección cuando haga clic en un elemento a de la navegacion lateral

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hola amigos estoy trabajando en un dashboard para crear un curso y tengo una duda.

Cuando hago clic en la navegación lateral me gustaría enfocar la sección a la que le di clic.

Cada sección está dentro de un acordion así que cuando le de clic se abre el acordión y luego debería enfocar el elemento pero esto no ocurre.

Para lograr el enfoque tengo que hacer doble clic en el elemento a de la navegación lateral y no debería funcionar de esa manera.

Mi código es:

```js
// abre la navegacion lateral
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("course__sidebar").style.transform = "translate(0px)";
}

// cierra la navegacion lateral izquierda
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("course__sidebar").style.transform = "translate(-300px)";
}

// modo oscuro
function darkSide(){
  var ladoOscuro, cuerpo;

  ladoOscuro = document.querySelector('.darkSide');
  cuerpo = document.querySelector('body');

  ladoOscuro.classList.toggle('dark');
  cuerpo.classList.toggle('dark');
}

function irAtras(){
  document.location.href = "../";
}

function myFunction() {
  var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
  document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = scrolled + "%";
}

// Get the button
var mybutton = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, show the button
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction(); myFunction();}

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    mybutton.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    mybutton.style.display = "none";
  }
}

// When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
function topFunction() {
  document.body.scrollTop = 0;
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}

// Filtrar lista


// Acordión
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var e;
var panel = document.querySelector('.panel');
var i;
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (e = 0; e < acc.length; e++) {
  acc[e].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}

var panelDOM = document.querySelectorAll('.panel');

// Abrir acordión desde la navegación
for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
  a[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    acc[i].classList.toggle('active');
    for (j = 0; j < acc.length; j++) {
      if (j !== i)
        acc[j].classList.remove('active');
        acc[j].nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null;
    }
    if (panelDOM[i].style.maxHeight) {
      panelDOM[i].style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panelDOM[i].style.maxHeight = panelDOM[i].scrollHeight + "px";
    }
    
  });
}


// busqueda por filtro

function buscarNav(){
  var entrada, filtro, anchor, v, valorText;
  entrada = document.getElementById('miEntrada');
  filtro = entrada.value.toUpperCase();
  anchor = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

  for(v = 0; v < anchor.length; v++){
    valorText = anchor[v].textContent || anchor[v].innerText;
    if(valorText.toUpperCase().indexOf(filtro) > -1){
      anchor[v].style.display = "";
    }else{
      anchor[v].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body{
    transition: .5s;
    background: #F0DB4F;
}

.articles{
    width: 60%;
    height: 500px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    box-shadow: var(--box-shadow);
}

section{
    padding: 20px;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

section h1{
    margin: 20px;
    border-width: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em;
}

section h2{
    margin: 20px 0px;
}

section h3{
    margin: 20px 0px;
}

section h4{
    margin: 20px 0px;
}


section p{
    text-align: justify;
    line-height: 30px;
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0px;
}

section img{
    margin: 20px 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

section ul{
    margin: 20px;
}

section ul li{
    margin: 10px;
}

section ol{
    margin: 20px;
}

section ol li{
    margin: 10px;
}

#course__sidebar{
    background: var(--color-2);
    width: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    transition: .3s;
    transform: translate(-300px);
    box-shadow: var(--box-shadow);

}

#course__sidebar a{
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    transition: .3s;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: var(--text-shadow);
}

#course__sidebar a:hover{
    background: var(--color-1);
    color: #fff;
    border-left: 10px solid var(--color-3);
}

#course__sidebar h3{
    color: var(--color-3);
}

.closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: -3px;
    right: 0px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .3s;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
}

.closebtn:hover{
    transform: scale(1.1) rotate(-90deg);
    color: var(--color-3);
}

.botones{
    position: fixed;
    top: 40%;
    padding: 20px;
}

.botones > div{
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    margin: 10px 0px;
}

.botones > div:hover{
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.dark{
    background: var(--color-1);
}

.openbtn{
    transition: .3s;
    padding: 10px;
    background: var(--color-2);
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10%;
    cursor: pointer; 
    z-index: 1;
}  

.openbtn:hover{
    transform: rotate(130deg);
}

.gobackbtn{
    transition: .3s;
    padding: 10px;
    background: var(--color-5);
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10%;
    cursor: pointer; 
    z-index: 1;
}

.gobackbtn:hover{
    transform: rotate(130deg);
}

.darkSide{
    transition: .3s;
    padding: 10px;
    background: var(--color-1);
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10%;
    cursor: pointer; 
    z-index: 1;
}

.darkSide:hover{
    transform: rotate(130deg);
}

.darkSide.dark{
    background: #F0DB4F;
}

.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.progress-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    background: #ccc;
}

.progress-bar {
    height: 5px;
    background: var(--color-2);
    width: 0%;
}


.codigo__nodejs{
    margin: 20px 0px;
}

.nota{
    background: #ffffcc;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px 0px;
}

.codigo{
    color: crimson;
    background: #f1f1f1;
}

.resultado{
    background: #fffeff;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px 0px;
    border: 3px dashed var(--color-principal);
}

.resultado h1{
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 0;
    color: #000;
}

.resultado p{
    font-size: 1em;
}

.precaucion{
    background: #ffdddd;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px 0px;
}

#myBtn {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 30px;
    z-index: 99;
    font-size: 18px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background-color: var(--color-1);
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    transition: .3s;
}

#myBtn i{
    color: #fff;
}

#myBtn:hover {
    opacity: .5;
}

table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 20px 0px;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}

/*  --------------- acordeón ---------------  */
#myInput{
    margin: 10px 0px;
    padding: 10px;
}
/*  --------------- acordeón ---------------  */

/*  --------------- acordeón ---------------  */

.accordion {
    background-color: var(--color-2);
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.4s;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
    background-color: var(--color-1);
}

.accordion:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
    content: "\2212";
}

.panel {
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

/*  --------------- acordeón ---------------  */

/*  --------------- search box ---------------  */

.search-container{
    display: flex;
    margin: 10px 0px;
}

input[type=text] {
    border: none;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}

.search-container button {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #ddd;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}


/*  --------------- search box ---------------  */


/*  --------------- mobile ---------------  */


@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){

    #myBtn{
        display: none !important;
    }

    section{
        padding: 20px;
        border-width: 5px;
        background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        box-shadow: var(--sombra-de-caja);
    }

    .botones{
        position: fixed;
        top: 40%;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    
    .articles{
        width: 80%;
        
    }

}

/*  --------------- mobile ---------------  */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>tutorial</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cooltipz-css/cooltipz.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
</head>

<body>
        <div class="botones">
                <div class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()" data-cooltipz-dir="right" aria-label="Barra de navegación"></div>
                <div class="darkSide" onclick="darkSide()" data-cooltipz-dir="right" aria-label="Modo Oscuro"></div>
                <div class="gobackbtn" onclick="irAtras()" data-cooltipz-dir="right" aria-label="Ir atrás"></div>
        </div>

        <aside id="course__sidebar">
                
                <div href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()"><i class="fal fa-times"></i></div>
                <h3>curso</h3>

                <div class="search-container">
                
                <input type="text" placeholder="Buscar..." name="buscar" onkeyup="buscarNav()" id="miEntrada">
                <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                
                </div>

                <a href="#item1">item 1</a>
                <a href="#item2">item 2</a>
                <a href="#item3">item 3</a>
                <a href="#item4">item 4</a>
                <a href="#item5">item 5</a>
                
        </aside>

        <div class="articles">
        
        <button class="accordion">Conversión de tipos</button>
        <div class="panel">
                <section id="item1">

                <h2>item 1</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint maxime culpa magnam a tenetur perspiciatis? Suscipit at mollitia sapiente quisquam velit officia autem id quos. Odit doloremque dolores repellat alias.</p>

                </section>
        </div>


        <button class="accordion">Conversión de tipos</button>
        <div class="panel">
                <section id="item2">

                <h2>item 2</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint maxime culpa magnam a tenetur perspiciatis? Suscipit at mollitia sapiente quisquam velit officia autem id quos. Odit doloremque dolores repellat alias.</p>

                </section>
        </div>

        <button class="accordion">Estructuras de control de flujo</button>
        <div class="panel">
                <section id="item3">

                <h2>item 3</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint maxime culpa magnam a tenetur perspiciatis? Suscipit at mollitia sapiente quisquam velit officia autem id quos. Odit doloremque dolores repellat alias.</p>

                </section>
        </div>

        <button class="accordion">Funciones</button>
        <div class="panel">
                <section id="item4">

                <h2>item 4</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint maxime culpa magnam a tenetur perspiciatis? Suscipit at mollitia sapiente quisquam velit officia autem id quos. Odit doloremque dolores repellat alias.</p>

                </section>
        </div>

        <button class="accordion">Objetos</button>
        <div class="panel">
                <section id="item5">

                <h2>item 5</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint maxime culpa magnam a tenetur perspiciatis? Suscipit at mollitia sapiente quisquam velit officia autem id quos. Odit doloremque dolores repellat alias.</p>

                </section>
        </div>

        </div>

        <button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Ir arriba"><i class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i></button>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.23.0/prism.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.23.0/plugins/autoloader/prism-autoloader.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./main.js"></script>
        <script src="./js/script.js"></script>
        </body>
</html>
```

Muchas gracias por tu ayuda :)

Comment: Me tomé la libertad de editar la pregunta para poner todo en un fragmento de código, pero hay errores. Por favor edita para solucionarlo y, a partir de [un ejemplo mínimo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), podemos tratar de ayudarte.

Comment: Gracias, cuando le doy clic a cualquier elemento de la navegacion ejemplo item 1 me gustaria que cuando se abra determinado panel de esa seccion se enfoque también. para lograr esto tengo que hacer clic nuevamente en el item o arrastrar hasta llegar ahí, es solo enfocar esa sección especifica y listo.

Comment: ¿Cómo hago para ver la barra? Edita la pregunta para solucionar eso y después podemos tratar de ayudar con lo demás.